# java - validate database with an array and execute after that

Tags: java, mysql, arrays

i have this code where the code just show the JOptionPane "ga kenek" on the second array

```
int rows = jTable1.getRowCount();
        for (int a = 0; a < rows; a++) {
            String namaop = jTable1.getValueAt(a, 0).toString();
            String tgl = jTable1.getValueAt(a, 1).toString();
            String pn = jTable1.getValueAt(a, 2).toString();
            String nama = jTable1.getValueAt(a, 3).toString();
            String sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_coba`(`a`, `b`, `c`,`d`)"
                    + " VALUES ('" + namaop + "','" + tgl + "','" + pn + "','"+nama+"')";
            String sql1="SELECT a FROM `tbl_coba`";
            try {
                Statement st=con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql1);
                if (rs.next()) {                        
                    Statement st1=con.createStatement();
                    if (namaop.equals(rs.getString("a"))) {//this is why this code was skipped
                        st1.executeUpdate(sql);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ""+namaop+"");
                        st1.close();
                    }else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ga kenek");
                    }
                }
            } catch (SQLException | HeadlessException e) {
                System.out.println(sql);
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR!!!");
            }
        }JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "iki for");
```

i'm stuck on this code because an arrays only executed on first array and this code `if (namaop.equals(rs.getString("a")))` just skipped

Comment: don´t doubt java here, that it skips an `if` statment. You rather have a flaw in the code.

Comment: sorry, i'm new on this